# Get f statistics and more from lm inside ggplot in a facet_wrap plot as label

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, facet-wrap

I got a lm function from a dataframe with a group. The group in the dataframe dfg is facet_wrapped and in each facet_wrap plot I would like to show the function of the lm. What I have done so far including the example dataframe + code you find below. Now I would like to add the f statistics and R value and DF...I have no idea how I can get those..anyone would like to help? I tried `substitute(italic(r)~"="~rvalue; list(rvalue = sprintf("%.2f",sign(coef(m)[2])*sqrt(summary(m)$r.squared))`  for the R value...but it doesnt work. Thanks in advance

I have this one (and it works):

```
dfg <- data.frame(x = c(1:100))
dfg$y <- 20 * c(0, 1) + 3 * df$x + rnorm(100, sd = 40)
dfg$group <- factor(rep(c("A", "B"), 50))

lm_eqn = function(dfg){
  m = lm(y ~ x, dfg);
  
  eq <- substitute(italic(y) == a + b %.% italic(x)*","~~italic(r)^2~"="~r2*","~~p~"="~italic(pvalue),
                   list(a = format(coef(m)[1], digits = 2), 
                        b = format(coef(m)[2], digits = 2), 
                        r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3),
                        pvalue = format(summary(m)$coefficients[2,'Pr(>|t|)'], digits=1)
                   )
  )
  as.character(as.expression(eq));                 
}
eq <- ddply(dfg,.(group),lm_eqn)

ggplot(data = dfg, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~group)+
  geom_smooth(aes(x = x, y = y), inherit.aes = FALSE, se = TRUE, col="black",span = 3)+
  geom_text(data=eq,aes(x = 25, y = 300,label=V1), parse = TRUE, inherit.aes=FALSE, size = 4)
```

Comment: This doesnt work for the R: substitute(italic(r)~"="~rvalue; list(rvalue = sprintf("%.2f",sign(coef(m)[2])*sqrt(summary(m)$r.squared))

Comment: What does "it doesnt work" mean? You need to replace `;` with `,` and fix the parentheses but the code for r looks fine.

Comment: Replacing the ; for , gives me an error that it needs,. For the R value it gives me an error: Error: unexpected symbol in:
"list(rvalue = sprintf("%.2f",sign(coef(m)[2])*sqrt(summary(m)$r.squared))
  as.character"

Comment: That's just a missing parenthesis and linebreak.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Your errors are simple syntax errors.

Comment: Maybe I am blind, but I cant see the error giving one..Can you help me out?